# Enum generalization?

Tags: java, android

In my project I have two chunk of code which I would like to separate to make one part a library. Yesterday, when I was trying to separate it I notice that there is a very strong connection between my new library and my application layer which is caused by Enum type. Of course I could simply change that Enum into the primary type of int, or a String and by this enabling myself to define those values within the application layer, but by doing it I would get rid of the type-check mechanism which I would like to have. Is there any other way to achieve it without loosing the type checking mechanism of Java/Android?
And the issue:

### Application Layer

Enum Id {...} // how to generalize the type?

### Library Layer

SomeClass.someMethod(Id myResource) {...}

Comment: If the library uses the enum, then the enum should be defined by the library, not by the application.

Comment: @JBNizet the library should use the type which is defined in application layer. I can achieve this by making the type int, or a  String but then the code will become type unsafe

Comment: How could the library use a type it doesn't even know? Could you provide a concrete example of such an enum, and of a library method using this enum?

Comment: @JBNizet I have a library which store some resources. Each resource is associated with unique enum value. Depending on the project I would like to have different set of enums (each project has different set of resources)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use an enum in your library. Use an interface, that the application will have to implement the way it wants to (by using an enum, for example).

The interface should contain the methods that are needed by the library. Without a more concrete example, it's hard to provide a more concrete answer.

For example:

```
public interface Identifiable {
    /**
     * returns the ID of the resource, that must unique among all the resources
     */
    public String getId();
}

public class SomeClass
    public void someMethod(Identifiable identifiable) {
        // some code that uses identifiable.getId()
    }
}
```

And in the application:

```
public enum Id implements Identifiable {
    FOO,
    BAR;

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return name();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, this is what I wanted to avoid, as the resources I'm using are for the purposes of real-time game, which of course needs to work with a decent speed. It seems that I will have to stick up with a simple int type in this case. Anyway thanks for educational code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

would this work for you:

```
import java.util.*;
enum Resources {
    r1("foo"),r2("bar"),r3("baz");
    Resources(String string) {
        this.string=string;
    }
    final String string;
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EnumSet<Resources> set1=EnumSet.of(Resources.r1,Resources.r2); // project 1
        EnumSet<Resources> set2=EnumSet.of(Resources.r1,Resources.r3); // project 2
    }
}
```